# Google Analytics Event tracking javascript getting stripped

Tags: wygwam

I'm trying to add Google Analytics Event tracking javascript snippet to A HREF link in Wygwam, but Wygwam keeps stripping out most of the snippet.

what i'm trying to add:

```
onClick=”_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'assessments', 'UPI', 'signup, '5', true]);”
```

as so:

```
Click <a href="URL" onClick=”_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'assessments', 'UPI', 'signup, '5', true]);” target="_blank">here</a>.
```

what it turns to when i save:

```
onclick="”_gaq.push(['_trackEvent',"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey - can you add some code tags around your code?  And update with version numbers for EE and Wygwam?  Happy to help, just need more details!  Also, are you adding this code in Source mode or normal mode?

Comment: Yes, more details please...